# make an output directory in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, directory

I'm trying to save an .eps file in a folder that doesn't exist yet. I wrote the following gnuplot script:

```
plot [0:0.13][0:55] 'example/x_-4_U.xy'
set output 'output/x=-4.eps'
replot
```

The script only works if the "output" folder is already there . Can I create this folder with gnuplot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the system command:

```
system "mkdir output"
```

on Linux, I seem to remember that it is `md output` on Windows.

Combined with string operators, this is rather flexible:

```
dir = "output1"
command = "mkdir " . dir
system command
```

works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the name of the output file with the folder name:

```
folderout = 'output/'
plot [0:0.13][0:55] 'example/x_-4_U.xy'
set output folderout.'x=-4.eps'
replot
```

Sincerely.